# automake -- SUBDIRS -- "No such file or directory"

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I am using autoconf/automake for my build system. So far it has been working just fine. However, I want to split some code out into another lib that I will be loading dynamically from within my main library. This is where I have run into an issue. The `Makefile.am` structure is as follows:

```
# Makefile.am
SUBDIRS = lib test bin stages_lib
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
CLEANFILES = *.o
CLEANDIRS = deps/ .lib/
```

```
# stages_lib/Makefile.am
SUBDIRS = lib
```

```
# stages_lib/lib/Makefile.am
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libstages_lib.la

libstages_lib_la_CPPFLAGS = -Werror -Wall -pedantic \
    -I$(abs_top_srcdir)/include/ \
    -I$(abs_top_srcdir)/stages_lib/include \
    -I$(abs_top_srcdir)/deps/build/boost/include

libstages_lib_la_SOURCES = print_stage.cxx

libstages_lib_la_LDFLAGS = -L$(abs_top_srcdir)/deps/build/boost/lib
if LINUX
libstages_lib_la_LDFLAGS += -L$(abs_top_srcdir)/deps/build/openssl/lib64
else
libstages_lib_la_LDFLAGS += -L$(abs_top_srcdir)/deps/build/openssl/lib
endif
libstages_lib_la_LDFLAGS += -libdag_scheduler -lboost_filesystem -lboost_log -lboost_system \
    -lboost_thread -lssl -lcrypto -pthread

if LINUX
libstages_lib_la_LIBADD = $(INIT_LIBS) -lm
else
libstages_lib_la_LIBADD = $(INIT_LIBS)
endif
```

With this setup, noting that the `lib`, `test`, and `bin` SUBDIRS build just fine. When I run the following from the root directory of my project:

```
> autoreconf -i
> rm -rf ./build && mkdir -p ./build
> cd build/ && ../configure
> cd ../
> make -C build
```

I now get the following error:

```
Making all in stages_lib
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: stages_lib: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: It's odd that when you're already in working directory `build/`, you don't just `make` from there.  But that shouldn't be causing your problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I do that so when I open vim and start working my pwd is in the root directory. From within vim I run `:make -C build` and have the diagnostics piped to copen. That is really the only reason for that awkward step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you must have forgotten to add `stages_lib/Makefile` and `stages_lib/lib/Makefile` to the `AC_CONFIG_FILES` list in your `configure.ac`. Supposing that you have a `Makefile.am` in each directory mentioned, and no directories have escaped mention, you want something along these lines:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
  Makefile
  lib/Makefile
  test/Makefile
  bin/Makefile
  stages_lib/Makefile
  stages_lib/lib/Makefile
])
```

`configure` could not have generated those files within your build directory without also creating the `stages_lib` directory, but `make` is denying that that directory exists.

Additional notes:

- Automake already knows how to clean.  Only in exceptional cases do you need to use `CLEANFILES` to tell it about files to clean -- generally this is when you have added custom rules.  But when you *do* use `CLEANFILES` for that purpose you should specify the actual file names, not globs.
- To the best of my knowledge, `CLEANDIRS` is not meaningful to Automake.  It's certainly not documented in [the current manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/index.html).
- you can put `-L` options either in `foo_LDFLAGS` or in `foo_LIBADD`, but `-l` options should go only in `foo_LIBADD` (or in `foo_LDADD` if `foo` is a program).